# takePicture() in Android Camera API fails immediately; surface behaves ok

Tags: android, api, camera

I implemented a fairly standard preview and button for simple picture taking, and the surface works as expected, even with an emulator attached to my laptop's webcam. The preview should always be started before onPictureTaken() can run, so that doesn't appear to be the issue.

```html
package com.davepeyton.android.seekbromance;

/**
 * Created by Dave on 6/5/2016.
 */

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class BrofileCameraFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "BrofileCameraFragment";
    public static final String EXTRA_PHOTO_FILENAME = "com.davepeyton.android.seekbromance.photo_filename";
    private Camera mCamera;
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private View mProgressContainer;

    private Camera.ShutterCallback mShutterCallback = new Camera.ShutterCallback() {
        public void onShutter() {
            // Display the progress indicator
            mProgressContainer.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE);
            }
    };

    private Camera.PictureCallback mJpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            // Create a filename
            String filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ". jpg";
            // Save the jpeg data to disk
            FileOutputStream os = null;
            boolean success = true;
            try {
                os = getActivity().openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                os.write(data);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error writing to file " + filename, e);
                success = false;
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (os != null)
                        os.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error closing file " + filename, e);
                    success = false;
                }
            }
            if (success) {
                Log.i(TAG, "JPEG saved at " + filename);
                // Pass the filename to BrofileSelfiePreviewFragment
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.putExtra(EXTRA_PHOTO_FILENAME, filename);
                getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
            } else {
                getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
            }
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    };

        /** A simple algorithm to get the largest size available. For a more robust version, see
         * CameraPreview.java in the ApiDemos sample app from Android. */
    private Size getBestSupportedSize(List <Camera.Size> sizes, int width, int height) {
        Size bestSize = sizes.get( 0);
        int largestArea = bestSize.width * bestSize.height;
        for (Size s : sizes) {
            int area = s.width * s.height;
            if (area > largestArea) {
                bestSize = s; largestArea = area;
            }
        }
        return bestSize;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.brofile_camera, parent, false);
        mProgressContainer = v.findViewById(R.id.brofile_camera_progressContainer);
        mProgressContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Button takePictureButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.brofile_camera_takePictureButton);
        takePictureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mCamera != null) {
                   mCamera.takePicture(mShutterCallback, null, null, mJpegCallback);
                }
            }
        });
        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView)v.findViewById(R.id.brofile_camera_surfaceView);
        SurfaceHolder holder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        // Note that setType() and SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS are both deprecated.
        // However, they are needed for the Camera view to work on pre-3.0 devices.

        holder.addCallback( new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        // A callback is required to coordinate the Surface's life cycle with the camera's preview.

            public void surfaceCreated( SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // Tells the camera to use this surface as its preview area
            try { if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay( holder);
                 }
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                Log.e( TAG, "Error setting up preview display", exception);
                 }
            }
            public void surfaceDestroyed( SurfaceHolder holder) {
                // We can no longer display on this surface, so stop the preview.
                if (mCamera != null) {
                    mCamera.stopPreview();
                    }
            }

            public void surfaceChanged( SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
                if (mCamera == null) return;
                // The surface has changed size; update the camera preview size
                Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
                Size s = getBestSupportedSize(parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes(), w, h);
                parameters.setPreviewSize( s.width, s.height);
                s = getBestSupportedSize(parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes(), w, h);
                parameters.setPictureSize(s.width, s.height);
                mCamera.setParameters( parameters);
                try {
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e( TAG, "Could not start preview", e);
                    mCamera.release();
                    mCamera = null; }
                } });

            return v;
    }

    @TargetApi(9)
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
            mCamera = Camera.open(0);
        } else {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the logcat. The image does not appear to be saving any file.

```html
08-15 13:51:27.364: V/EmulatedCamera_QemuDevice(1140): startDevice: Qemu camera device 'AndroidEmulatorVC0' is started for NV21[640x480] frames
08-15 13:51:27.364: V/EmulatedCamera_Device(1140): startDeliveringFrames
08-15 13:51:27.364: V/EmulatedCamera_Device(1140): startWorkerThread
08-15 13:51:27.365: D/AndroidRuntime(2738): Shutting down VM
08-15 13:51:27.365: D/AndroidRuntime(2738): --------- beginning of crash
08-15 13:51:27.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2738): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 13:51:27.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2738): Process: com.davepeyton.android.seekbromance, PID: 2738
08-15 13:51:27.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2738): java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
08-15 13:51:27.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2738):  at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
08-15 13:51:27.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2738):  at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1436)
08-15 13:51:27.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2738):  at com.davepeyton.android.seekbromance.BrofileCameraFragment$3.onClick(BrofileCameraFragment.java:106)
08-15 13:51:27.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2738):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
08-15 13:51:27.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2738):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
08-15 13:51:27.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2738):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
08-15 13:51:27.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2738):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-15 13:51:27.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2738):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-15 13:51:27.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2738):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
08-15 13:51:27.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2738):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-15 13:51:27.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2738):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-15 13:51:27.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2738):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
08-15 13:51:27.365: E/AndroidRuntime(2738):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
08-15 13:51:27.366: V/EmulatedCamera_Device(1140): Starting emulated camera device worker thread...
08-15 13:51:27.366: V/EmulatedCamera_Device(1140): Emulated device's worker thread has been started.
```

Answer (score 0):

Because takePicture is async, there are probably issues with activity housekeeping within `mJpegCallback`.

The transition works as expected when these statements are moved to `onPause()` Of course, there's a check for the new photo's existence to make sure that the current activity is actually being destroyed. Which is the intention after a successful photo is taken.